# Check user policies in ASP.NET Core Identity from database

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor-server-side, asp.net-core-identity

I am using Blazor Server and Identity without Entity Framework. So far I managed to get authentication running. I can register users and change everything.

But I now I want to get started with authorization and I think that for my purpose policy-based authorization might be the best way:

Let's say I have invoices and every CRUD action has its own policy like `CreateInvoices`, `ReadInvoices`, `UpdateInvoices` and `DeleteInvoices`. I want to create groups with those policy assigned.

If a user tries to create an invoice, the "system" would check if any of the groups the user is member in has the policy `CreateInvoices` assigned. The database query is clear and populating the Blazor component is clear to me.

I also know that I would need a custom AuthorizationPolicyHandler, -Provider and -Requirement.

I don't want anybody to code for me but do give me direction and understanding :)

I assume the handler queries the database and returns some value "allowed" and the PolicyProvider is the overall "framework" which will be injected?

Comment: If I understand you correctly you're looking for a Claims-based authorization - see this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/claims?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: @riffnl I thought so myself but the article states "A claim is a name value pair that represents what the subject is, not what the subject can do". Am I wrong here?

Comment: Well yes and no. The claim itself does not represent anything. The policy does. For instance create a policy "CreateInvoice" can lead to something like : options.AddPolicy("CreateInvoice", policy => policy.RequireClaim("CreateInvoices"));

Comment: Okay, I understand. But how do I avoid using `options.AddPolicy("CreateInvoice", policy => policy.RequireClaim("CreateInvoices"));`? It could happen that there will be tens or even hundrets of claims (I want ACL based). And the permissions will be assigned at runtime.

Comment: You can create your own handler for this - I will attempt to write an in-depth answer

Comment: @riffnl Some psuedo-code would suffice!!!

Comment: If the answer helped you, please mark it as correct or comment for more information

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create your own handler for this. You'll need a filter, an attribute and a handler to do this; code below is a bit pseudo-coded, but you can extrapolate your specific case for this. For instance I use an enum as permission, but you can use anything really.

First the enum:

```
    public enum Permissions
    {
        None = 0,
        CreateInvoice = 1,
        DeleteInvoice = 2,
    }
```

And you'll need a filter (also needed to be added at StartUp - that will come later)

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;

namespace Site.Permissions
{
    public class PermissionRequirementFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
    {
        readonly Permissions _permission;
        private readonly PermissionHandler _handler;

        public PermissionRequirementFilter(PermissionHandler handler)
        {
            _handler = handler;
        }

        public PermissionRequirementFilter(Permissions permission, PermissionHandler handler)
        {
            _permission = permission;
            _handler = handler;
        }

        public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
        {
            if (!_handler.HasPermission(_permission)) context.Result = new ForbidResult();
        }
    }
}
```

You'll need an attribute (because you want to prefix your methods with a specific permission)

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;

namespace Site.Permissions
{
    public class PermissionRequirementAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute
    {
        public PermissionRequirementAttribute(Permissions permission) : base(typeof(PermissionRequirementFilter))
        {
            Arguments = new object[] { permission };
        }
    }
}
```

And you'll need a handler - this is where you actually check conditions, in this handler (class) you'll need to have a method called HasPermission but also access to the actual logged in user, so you need some method to get the authorized user from the IHttpContextAccessor.

Below is a bit pseudocoded, the CurrentUser get the user and the HasClaim can do something with that user, but that's the gist of it; also as you can see with DeleteInvoice you can build your own requirements as well as use the correct claims, in this case I assume you need to be an administrator the delete the invoice - this may not be the case, but it's for example purposes.

HasPermission has only 1 needed parameter which is (in this case) the permission enum, something like this:

```
public bool HasPermission(Permissions request)
{
    if (CurrentUser == null) return false;
    switch (request)
    {
        case Permissions.CreateInvoice: return HasClaim("CreateInvoice");
        case Permissions.DeleteInvoice: return IsAdmin && HasClaim("DeleteInvoice");
        case Permissions.None:
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```

In StartUp `ConfigureServices` you need to register your handler and your filter:

```
    services.AddScoped<PermissionHandler>();
    services.AddScoped<PermissionRequirementFilter>();
```

And in your controller you can add this:

```
[Permissions.PermissionRequirement(Permissions.Permissions.CreateInvoice)]
public IActionResult CreateInvoice(Guid? id)
{
    return View(new Models.Invoice());
}
```

Your controller itself should have the `[Authorize]` attribute as well.

The handler can also be used, while showing your page if the user has a permission. No need to show "Delete invoice" button when the user is not authorized to do so.

Hope this will help you along.